# How to create script with Insert statement for the records selected in MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to create a script file with the Insert statements for the records I select in the mysql table.

For Instance, when i do `Select * from emp where empid = 5`, and say i get 10 records as result.
Now I should create a script file with the insert statements of that 10 records to emp table.

I am using C# as code behind...

How?

Comment: As nobody know what you want to insert, you'd better give an example of your table, data, and these insert queries.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I have two databases A and B. Both these databases have same table schema. So i want to select from one table and insert in the similar table in another database. For which i need to create a Insert script for whatever selected records. writing a script here is for my project req.

Comment: Offcourse you know that if both tables are on the same server, you can just INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A, right? (or improvements on that query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sample`.`InsGen` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsGen`(
in_db varchar(20),
in_table varchar(20),
in_ColumnName varchar(20),
in_ColumnValue varchar(20)
)
BEGIN

declare Whrs varchar(500);
declare Sels varchar(500);
declare Inserts varchar(200);
declare tablename varchar(20);
declare ColName varchar(20);


set tablename=in_table;


# Comma separated column names - used for Select
select group_concat(concat('concat(\'"\',','ifnull(',column_name,','''')',',\'"\')'))
INTO @Sels from information_schema.columns where table_schema=in_db and table_name=tablename;


# Comma separated column names - used for Group By
select group_concat('`',column_name,'`')
INTO @Whrs from information_schema.columns where table_schema=in_db and table_name=tablename;


#Main Select Statement for fetching comma separated table values

 set @Inserts=concat("select concat('insert IGNORE into ", in_db,".",tablename," values(',concat_ws(',',",@Sels,"),');')
 as MyColumn from ", in_db,".",tablename, " where ", in_ColumnName, " = " , in_ColumnValue, " group by ",@Whrs, ";");

 PREPARE Inserts FROM @Inserts;

EXECUTE Inserts;                    

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well now your question makes sense.
You can do it within one query

```
INSERT INTO B.emp SELECT * FROM A.emp WHERE empid = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked  with Norhtwind.Customer table.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Odbc;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    namespace DataAccessLayer
    {      
        public class DBManager
        {   
            //FILE LOGGER METHOD
            public  void SqlLogger(string SqlText)
            {  if (!File.Exists("SQL.txt"))
                {  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("SQL.txt"))
                    {   sw.Flush();
                        sw.Close();
                        sw.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("SQL.txt"))
                {   sw.WriteLine(SqlText);
                    sw.WriteLine(" ");
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.Close();
                    sw.Dispose();
                }

            }

            // DATABASE METHODS
            public static OdbcConnection g_con = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=wsodbc1");      
            public DBManager()
            {

            }
            public OdbcConnection GetConnection()

            {  try   {   g_con.Open();         }
                catch (Exception ex)     {        }
                return g_con;            
            }
            public OdbcCommand GetCommand(string Query)
            {
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(Query);
                cmd.Connection = GetConnection();
                return cmd;
            }
            public void ExeCommand(string Query)
            {
                OdbcCommand cmd = GetCommand(Query);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    


            }
            public OdbcDataReader GetReader(string Query)
            {  return GetCommand(Query).ExecuteReader();     }

            // SQL INSERT GENERATOR
            public void GenerateSql(string tablename)
            {
                File.Delete("SQL.txt");
                List<string> cols = new List<string>();
                string ColNames;


                OdbcDataReader reader = GetReader("SELECT     * FROM         Customers ");

                DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

                foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
                {   foreach (DataColumn column in schemaTable.Columns)
                {          
                    if (column.ColumnName.Equals("ColumnName")) cols.Add(row[column].ToString().ToUpper());                    
                    }
                }


                    ColNames = string.Join(",", cols.ToArray());


                    while (reader.Read())
                {

                    SqlLogger("INSERT INTO " + tablename + " (" + ColNames + ") VALUES (" + Row_Values(reader) + ")");

                }

            }
            public string Row_Values(OdbcDataReader r)
            {
                    List<string> colsVals = new List<string>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < r.FieldCount; i++ )
                    {

                        if (r[i].GetType().ToString().Equals("System.String"))
                        {
                            if (r[i] == null)
                            {
                                colsVals.Add("NULL");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                colsVals.Add("'" + r[i].ToString().Replace("'","''").Replace(",","-") + "'");
                            }

                        }
                        else if (r[i].GetType().ToString().Equals("System.DBNull"))
                        {
                            colsVals.Add("NULL");
                        }
                        else

                        {
                            if (r[i] == null)
                            {
                                colsVals.Add("NULL");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var VAL = r[i].ToString();
                                colsVals.Add("'" + VAL.ToString().Replace("'", "''").Replace(",", "-") + "'");
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    return string.Join(",", colsVals.ToArray());   
            }
        }
    }
```